# Why I have this "count()" error in PHP search?

Tags: php-7.2

I'm sorry i just start php and i don't know and find why i have this error ?
My search function send me a result but with this error and i don't know why .. Thanks.

I try to finish my exercice without my profesor. I'm really beginner. I work on localhost with phpmyadmin.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] !== '') {
      $articles = searchArticle($_GET['search']);
      $numberArticles = count($articles) ;
    }
    else {
      $articles = readArticles();
    }
  ?>

  <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">

          <form class="text-white" action="index.php" name="searchform" method="get"> Rechercher un article
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Votre recherche">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Rechercher">

            <?php
                 if (isset($numberArticles)) {

                     if ($numberArticles > 1) {
                         echo '<p>' . $numberArticles . ' articles trouvés</p>';
                     }
                     else {
                         echo '<p>' . $numberArticles . ' article trouvé</p>';
                     }
                 }
             ?>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The PHP error :  "Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\wf3-html-blog\partials\header.php on line 47" . Line 47 is my code is the 4 in this ask

Comment: It looks as though the searchArticle() function isn't returning what the code here is expecting. Can you provide the code for this function?

Comment: Here the function searchArticle : function searchArticle($search) {
    $bdd = dbconnect();
    $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE titre LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR contenu LIKE '%" . $search . "%' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while ($search = $reponse->fetchAll());


    return $reponse;
}

Comment: In fact i try to make a search engine for my blog and after 3 weeks alone i think i'm lost .. ;)